# Como modificar a lista no código do wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Boa tarde, estou com problema no desenvolvimento. Quero saber como modifico a aparecencia do menu que estou fazendo.

No **`function.php`** está o seguinte código:

```
<?php
//menu
function register_my_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'header-menu' => __( 'Header Menu' ),
      'extra-menu' => __( 'Extra Menu' )
     )
   );
 }
 add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
?>
```

no arquivo **`header.php`** está como:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/style.css">
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>

</head>
<body>
<?php
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu', 'menu_class' => 'menuclasse' ) );
?>
```

e no arquivo **`style.css`**:

```
body{
    background: lightblue;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menuclasse{
    float: left;
}
.menu-item{
    background: blue;
}
```

Simplificando. O menu no site está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu coloco código **`float:left, text-style:none`**, não funciona. O meu objetivo é transformar em menu horizontal. Ele não aceita alguns códigos css, e para eu fazer eu preciso que aceite. Alguém poderia me dar uma auxilio?

Comment: desculpe, eu não formatei direito o código. Vou tirar uns prints e colocar o link.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/f/s!Ar8gcB6IdrJ-sD31P_hj8RDN7NaN. Esse é o código que eu tirei print. Então o meu objetivo é fazer um menu horizontal...

Answer (score 0):

Como seu objetivo é deixar o menu horizontal, basta acrescentar o seguinte código no seu CSS:

```
ul.menuclasse li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Desta forma você está falando para o elemento `<ul>` com a classe *.menuclasse* que os itens dentro do `<li>` devem se adequar à propriedade de display *inline-block*, responsável por ordenar os itens horizontalmente.

Espero ter ajudado.